# Parameter-dependent case statement in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a case statement inside sequential logic (an always block activated at the clock's posedge). The case is evaluating a variable `var` which's bit width depends on a parameter `PARAM`. I need to cover all of the possible values `var` can take in the case statement, which varies based on the value of `PARAM`. As an example, if `PARAM` is 32, `var` is 5 bits wide so there must be 32 cases. If `PARAM` is 16, `var` is 4 bits wide, requiring 16 cases. This case statement is also inside a nest of `if` statements, making it difficult for me to think of a way to bring it outside sequential logic (I've thought about conditional `generate` statements already). Any ideas on how to do this? Below is pseudo-code for the structure:

```
module a
#(parameter PARAM = 8,
  parameter WIDTH = $clog2(PARAM)
 )
...
input logic [WIDTH-1:0] var
...
always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    if(...)
      begin
        if(...)
          begin
            case(var)
              3'd0:
              3'd1:
              3'd2:
              3'd3:
              3'd4:
              3'd5:
              3'd6:
              3'd7:
              default:
            endcase
          end
      end
  end
```

In the example above, if `PARAM` takes its default value (8), there should be 8 cases. But if `PARAM` was 4 at instantiation, there should only be 4 cases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are going to need to show an example of what the code might look like. How would parameterize the code inside each case item?

Comment: There is no such thing in verilog. Most likely there is a different solution to your problem, but you need to provide an example to understand it. In the worst case you can probably generate verilog code using a script or some other method.

Comment: If you want a good answer, you're going to have to put in some effort to show a example stripped of the IP.

Comment: I looked again, but it still makes no sense. You can certainly explain further without giving any IP way. How do you expect the blocks of code inside the branches a,b,c,d to be parametrically created. Or can you statically define all the branches, and then limit the value of val based on your parameter?

Comment: @dave_59 now things should make more sense :)

Comment: Why do you even need to parameterize the case statement? The width of `var` will make the case items unreachable. I.e. if `PARAM = 4` case items 4-7 will be unreachable.

Comment: @dave_59 That's exactly my problem. I want the number of cases to be a function of `PARAM`. If `PARAM` is 4, I want the case block to only have 4 cases. If `PARAM` is 8, I want the case block to have 8 cases. I don't want to have unreachable cases for coverage testing reasons. In the example above, I wrote 8 cases but that is only what it should look like in the case `PARAM` is 8.

Comment: There are script you can write to deal with unreachable statements for code coverage. But the but big piece you keep missing is what the code inside each case item would like. Suppose you could put a generate inside a case statement, how does each case branch need to be different based on the parameter. i.e. what's different about each branch that it needs to be in a case statement.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you explained what val, a, b, c, and d are. Here is the best I can do

```
always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    if(...)
      begin
        if(...)
          begin
            if (param == 1 && (var inside {a,b})) 
               branch = var;
            else 
               branch =  a_value_that_is_not_a,b,c,d;
            case(branch)
              a:
              b:
              c:
              d:
              default:
            endcase
          end
      end
  end
```

Comment: Hi Dave! I've modified the question to be more clear. I apologize for not doing the best job at describing the problem at first. Thanks for the help!